# write to previous line in python

Tags: python

I am writing code to generate words from one file to another
I have done all ok but the problem that when I use line it feed a new line in the output file I want to next word after line to be written at the same line

the code

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write("<answer>" + line +"doit");
```

now doit comes in a new line in the out.txt

the text file has 3 lines
door
window
house

Comment: That is because there is a linefeed at the end of each line you are reading from `f`. Use `line.strip()` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `line` contains a `\n` at the end, which you have to remove yourself:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write("<answer>" + line[:-1] +"doit")
```

The problem of using `rstrip` as the other answer suggests is that you would lose ending spaces: `'  aa  \n'.rstrip()` gives you `'  aa'`. This might or might not be what you need.

Comment: `line.rstrip("\n")` is much better just in case the last line doesn't end by \n

Comment: Thank you sooo much it work perfectly . Millions thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `rstrip()` to remove the trailing `\n`

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            f1.write("<answer>" + line.rstrip('\n') +"doit");
```

Comment: line strap doesn't work with me , Thanks for your effort